# Convert snippet from c# to vbscript

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, asp-classic

So I have a situation where I need to pass some parameters on url.  In order to not have id=1 on the url, I added a simple encryption method to obfuscate the values.  This has worked fine within the .Net land.  Now however, I need to direct from a classic asp page to this .net page that is expecting the parameters to be encrypted.  I really am not too familiar with encryption or classic asp and was hoping someone would be able to direct me to a good JS lib, or simply provide a classic asp version of this function?  If there's anything wrong with the .Net code, I'd love to hear feedback on that as well.

Here's the encryption method:

```
public static string Encrypt(string Input)
{
    try
    {
        key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(EncryptionKey.Substring(0, 8));
        var des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        Byte[] inputByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Input);
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

And here's the decryption method (I need this to decrypt the classic asp encrypted text):

```
public static string Decrypt(string Input)
{
    try
    {
        key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(EncryptionKey.Substring(0, 8));
        var des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        var inputByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(Input);
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateDecryptor(key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();

        Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        return encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray());

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mean to answer my own question, but I couldn't get the code added as a comment.  Anyway, I ended up implementing RC4 on the client anyway.  For anyone who may be interested (wth are you doing working in classic asp?? :) )  Here's the relevant code - hope it helps!  As always, if anyone spots a problem with this snippet, please let me know!

Thanks,

Matt

```
Dim sbox(255)
Dim key(255)

Sub RC4Initialize(strPwd)
  dim tempSwap
  dim a
  dim b

  intLength = len(strPwd)
  For a = 0 To 255
     key(a) = asc(mid(strpwd, (a mod intLength)+1, 1))
     sbox(a) = a
  next

  b = 0
  For a = 0 To 255
     b = (b + sbox(a) + key(a)) Mod 256
     tempSwap = sbox(a)
     sbox(a) = sbox(b)
     sbox(b) = tempSwap
  Next

End Sub

Function EnDeCrypt(plaintxt)
  dim temp
  dim a
  dim i
  dim j
  dim k
  dim cipherby
  dim cipher

  i = 0
  j = 0

  RC4Initialize "somesortofpassword"

  For a = 1 To Len(plaintxt)
     i = (i + 1) Mod 256
     j = (j + sbox(i)) Mod 256
     temp = sbox(i)
     sbox(i) = sbox(j)
     sbox(j) = temp

     k = sbox((sbox(i) + sbox(j)) Mod 256)

     cipherby = Asc(Mid(plaintxt, a, 1)) Xor k
     dim h
     h = hex(cipherby)
     if Len(h) = 1 then
        h = "0" & h
      end if
     cipher = cipher & h
  Next

  EnDeCrypt = cipher
End Function
```

Answer (score 7):

This isn't some simple translation! Classic ASP doesn't have access to the .NET Framework. You would need to do all of this in Win32 code.

You should package the C# code together as a COM component, which can then be accessed from the Classic ASP site.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I considered doing this at one point, but I've had issues accessing custom com components when running under IIS x64.  Can anyone confirm this is or is not doable, and if there are any special considerations for implementing under x64?

Comment: You can access custom COM+ components in x64. I don't know if their are custom steps, but it is possible.  We have some legacy code doing it.

Comment: Go into your compile options and under advanced try for CPU targeting x64 specifically and then making sure it is set to register for COM Interop.

I have yet to have a problem once I have done that. Also I have found using a .NET deployment works better at registering the DLLs, though I have created BAT files as well, referencing the regasm commands manually.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, I'll be sure to try it out and post results.

Comment: While I didn't end up making this change, I feel it's probably the best solution in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this one on our site which uses ASP & VB.NET. Also, in-house utility programs are written in C#, VB6 & VB.NET. All of the programs needed to be able to exchange encrypted data.

To handle this problem I wrote a VB6 & VBScript encryption routine which I converted to .NET. It allows me to have identical data across the platforms. The encryption & hashing that I selected were RC4 and MD5. Both of which were considerably enhanced with multiple features, such as the MD5 is a salted version and the RC4 contains a CRC check and an option for double encrypting using multiple passkeys.

This is for the minimally sensitive data. For the data that is very sensitive, I wrote a VB6 DLL that does a DES-3 encryption. This DLL is then made available to all platforms.

I put the passkeys in the registry, encrypted using hardware parameters for the password using another encryption method. (If you get them from the registry and try to put them on another system, they're no good.)

Comment: Sounds like a sensible approach, just a bit all-encompassing for my needs currently.  I was hoping to find something that didn't require me to implement all of that - but thanks for the feedback as well!